# I keep getting "Ran out of input" error in for() function to open and adjust pickle file

Tags: python, eoferror

I was making stock data MACD calculator in python. The way of my approach is using `'for()'` to access pickle datas in certain directory and calculate MACD values one by one. However, I got 'Ran out of input error' everytime. I checked my directory where pickle datas are stored and it was not empty. Funny thing is, If I just put numbers in `i` position without using `'for()'`, I could get data of the pickle file. Please help me to get free from this error.

Here's my code:

'''

```
import pickle
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/pickle_data') 
os.chdir('/home/sejahui/projects/pickle_data')

for i in range(2):
    odd = file_list[i]
    with open(odd,'rb') as stock:
        data = pickle.load(stock)
    print(data)
```

'''

Comment: Why would you do `range(2)`?  How do you know the files you want are the first two?  Shouldn't you be checking the file extensions or something?  The error means the file is either damages or is not a pickle at all.

Comment: To test my code whether works well or not, I put 2 in range bracket.

Comment: To test my code whether works well or not, I put 2 in range bracket. If I don't use for(), I could read and get values of pickle files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, actually, you create a list with `file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/pickle_data')`. You do not need `range` to iterate.

The error is because sometimes there is only 1 file so it will be out of the index. The correct way is like this:

```
import pickle
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/pickle_data') 
os.chdir('/home/sejahui/projects/pickle_data')

for str in file_list:
   
    with open(str,'rb') as stock:
        data = pickle.load(stock)
    print(data)
```

You can even add an `if` statement to the filter based on a regex or pattern

```
if str == "something":
    with open(str,'rb') as stock:
        data = pickle.load(stock)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed help. But there's one more thing I want to know. If I just want to cut in some part of the list, what can I do? Also, the meaning of 'str' is the list what I made?

Comment: What do mean by cutting down the list? Do u mean that to find the specific file?
Also str here is the variable which in each iteration of the loop an element of the list will assign to it. And you pass it to your file.